# Volevo chiederle se + congiuntivo o condizionale?

Tags: verbs, subjunctive-mood, conditional-mood

Quale delle seguenti frasi è corretta?

1) Volevo chiederle se potesse farmi questo favore

2) Volevo chiederle se potrebbe farmi questo favore

Grazie

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Answer (score 8):

Secondo Treccani, in questo caso, entrambe le frasi possono considerarsi corrette.

Infatti [Treccani a riguardo dice](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_1077.html):

> **DOMANDA** È corretto dire: "volevo chiederle se potrebbe..." o va usato
>   il congiuntivo?
>  **RISPOSTA** Potrebbe aprire la finestra? Si tratta di un
>   inappuntabile condizionale di cortesia. Tale inappuntabile
>   condizionale di cortesia resta inappuntabile anche nell'interrogativa
>   indiretta volevo chiederle se potrebbe aprire la finestra. Insomma, il
>   condizionale, in questo caso, va bene.

In aggiunta, sempre su [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_565.html), c'è una spiegazione più organica al seguente quesito:

> **DOMANDA** Vorrei sapere se la domanda che segue è corretta o no. “Vorrei chiederle se potesse darmi qualche suggerimento a riguardo...”
>   
> **RISPOSTA** L'attenzione verte principalmente sulla consecutio
>   temporum. Nella dichiarativa, compare una forma di cortesia, che
>   attenua il tono diretto della richiesta, realizzabile in vari gradi a
>   scalare (Voglio chiederle, Le chiedo, Le chiederei) grazie
>   all'introduzione del verbo modale volere e all'adozione del
>   condizionale. Vorrei chiederle equivale dunque a Le chiederei: in
>   dipendenza da un condizionale (qui di cortesia, equivalente, di fatto,
>   a un presente indicativo più “gentile”), l'interrogativa indiretta
>   esplicita, portatrice di un'azione posteriore rispetto a quella della
>   reggente, seleziona il modo, tra congiuntivo e indicativo, a seconda
>   della maggiore o minore ricercatezza stilistica: vorrei chiederle se
>   possa darmi (più elevato) / vorrei chiederle se può darmi (standard).
>   In questo caso, può avere senso anche l'uso del condizionale, vale a
>   dire lo stesso modo che useremmo nell'interrogazione diretta, volendo
>   essere cortesi (Potrebbe darmi... ?): vorrei chiederle se potrebbe
>   darmi. Il tempo dell'interrogativa indiretta è il presente (o, al
>   limite, il futuro, nel caso di uso dell'indicativo: vorrei chiederle
>   se potrà darmi).
>
> Infine: non si scriva a riguardo, ma al riguardo, a questo riguardo, a
>   tale riguardo, se la frase si conclude e dunque ci riferiamo ad
>   affermazioni fatte in precedenza; riguardo a (al, alla, ai, ecc.) se i
>   puntini di sospensione preparano tali affermazioni (… suggerimento
>   riguardo al mio progetto).

Comment: Devo dire che su Italian.SE si impara sempre qualcosa.

Comment: Scusa, ma Treccani dice "il condizionale, in questo caso, va bene". Quindi, perché la prima frase sarebbe la corretta?

Comment: Sarebbe corretta in generale e in questo caso Treccani dice che si può usare il condizionale al posto del congiuntivo. Il mio ultimo edit chiarisce meglio il discorso. Chiaramente se pensi che generi confusione posso omettere il primo passaggio e riportare solo Treccani...

Comment: Quindi, forse la risposta dovrebbe essere che tutte e due la frasi sono corrette.

Comment: Corretta la risposta

Answer (score 3):

Riporto, riadattandola al caso la risposta dell'illustre linguista e filologo Luca Serianni, socio nazionale dell’Accademia dei Lincei, della Crusca e dell'Arcadia, in merito alla **sintassi del verbo nelle interrogative indirette**:

> **L'uso del congiuntivo è quello più comune** (e quindi **raccomandabile**), anche se *il condizionale*, pur situandosi *ai limiti dell'accettabilità*, *non può dirsi sbagliato*: la sequenza *se + condizionale*, lo ricordiamo, è inammissibile nella protasi di un periodo ipotetico (*Se lo vedrei, lo riconoscerei*), ma non c'è nessuna restrizione preliminare quando il se introduce un'interrogativa indiretta. Vero è che un condizionale in un'interrogativa indiretta introdotta da se è del tutto a suo agio solo quando la subordinata rappresenta l'apodosi di un periodo ipotetico con protasi non espressa (*Mi domando se direbbe le stesse le cose anche davanti a suo padre*; cioè *se ci fosse suo padre*), quando il condizionale esprime un valore specifico (per esempio condizionale di cortesia: *Mi chiedo se non le farebbe piacere andare a riposare*), oppure quando l'azione è proiettata al futuro (in tal caso oggi è obbligatorio il condizionale composto: *Mi chiedevo se sarebbe davvero partito*). [cfr. [link](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/sintassi-verbo-interrogative-indirette)]

Pertanto è meglio usare il congiuntivo, in quanto nell'esempio in questione non si presentano le modalità sopra riportate, e sebbene non possa dirsi sbagliato, vi sono comunque dubbi sulla correttezza grammaticale.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Comment: @Charo Grazie mille!