# (S)correttezza di "Se + congiuntivo + condizionale + se + condizionale"

Tags: subjunctive-mood, conditional-mood

(Non mi sto riferendo ad [un *se* che introduce un'interrogativa indiretta](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/8828/volevo-chiederle-se-congiuntivo-o-condizionale).)

Un esempio della costruzione nel titolo è presente in [una canzone degli 883](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BDD67_tA_kE):¹

> Se solo avessi le parole
>
> te lo direi
>
> anche se mi farebbe male

Mi chiedevo se tale utilizzo dei tempi è grammaticalmente corretto o scorretto, e quali regole lo stabiliscono.

Non posso fare a meno di notare che "semplici" riordinamenti fanno suonare la frase veramente brutta alle mie orecchie. Ad esempio

> Se solo avessi le parole e anche se mi farebbe male, te lo direi

mi suona molto molto cacofonico, benché stia esprimendo fondamentalmente lo stesso concetto.

---

(¹) Sì, lo so, il testo di una canzone non è esattamente la fonte cui dovrei attingere aspettandomi un totale rispetto della grammatica, però è almeno la prova che quell'uso dei tempi non è venuto in mente solo a me. Oltretutto, musicalmente *farebbe* e *facesse* giocano un ruolo identico, quindi di certo l'autore non ha scelto l'uno o l'altro tempo per accomodare la musica. Evidentemente gli sembrava più appropriato.

Comment: Questa non è un'istanza di `se` + `condizionale`, bensí di `anche se` + `condizionale`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Credo che il primo “se” non c'entri veramente; cioè, la questione è che qualcuno formula una situazione ipotetica, “ti direi X”, e una sua conseguenza altrettanto ipotetica, “mi farebbe male”. Quindi “ti direi X ma mi farebbe male” non crea alcun problema. Il problema viene solo dall'usare “anche se” al posto di “ma”, ma verrebbe anche dall'usare “sebbene”, “malgrado” o qualunque altro modo per introdurre una concessiva.

D'altro canto, anche se il modo verbale più usuale per una concessiva è il congiuntivo (“benché sia tardi, voglio finire”), in certi casi sono ammessi anche l'indicativo e il condizionale. Cito da Serianni, *Italiano*, XIV.175:

> il condizionale compare nei casi in cui comparirebbe in una frase enunciativa [...]: «farò un solo esempio, benché se ne potrebbero fare centomila» (Moravia [...]; valore eventuale, che presuppone un'apodosi sottintesa: «se ne potrebbero ... se si volesse»); «allora il sillabario servì, benché non avrebbe creduto mai che fosse impresa di tanto impegno e fatica» (Bacchelli, *Il mulino del Po*, I 90; valore attenuativo, come nelle frasi semplici che indicano «stupore, perplessità, imbarazzo» [...])

Quindi, se siamo d'accordo sulla mia analisi secondo cui “anche se mi farebbe male” è una concessiva, il condizionale è ammesso, anche se minoritario.